# bash: manager processes run

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, while-loop

I have multiple files in $tmpdir/$i.dirlist with entries command rsync.
Each file have (depending on the amount) 10 sometimes 50 and even 150 entries of rsync.

I'm wondering now how to manage it by FOR or WHILE loop with IF sequence to run from each files ($tmpdir/$i.dirlist - if we have have 100 files) only 2 entries and wait for complet some processes and if total of all running process of rsync are less than 200 processes - launched new entries, maintaining a fixed number of processes defined in the parameter. In this case 200

Any idea? how to do it?

Edit:
about rsync entry.
In each file $tmpdir/*.dirlist is (in this example 200) entries with directory

path like:

```
==> /tmp/rsync.23611/0.dirlist <==
system/root/etc/ssl
system/root/etc/dbus-1
system/root/etc/lirc
system/root/etc/sysctl.d

==> /tmp/rsync.23611/1.dirlist <==
system/root/etc/binfmt.d
system/root/etc/cit
system/root/etc/gdb

==> /tmp/rsync.23611/2.dirlist <==
system/root/usr/local
system/root/usr/bin
system/root/usr/lib
```

now to run it i use simply for

```
for i in $(seq 1 $rsyncs); do
    while read r; do 
        rsync $rsyncopts backup@$host:$remotepath/$ri $r 2>&1 | 
            tee $tmpdir/$i.dirlist.log ; 
    done < $tmpdir/$i.dirlist &
done
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a list of commands to execute from the files $tmpdir/*.dirlist, and you want to execute only 2 commands at the same time for each of the .dirlist files. I assume each time a process finishes, you want to start another one.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide any example (even shortened, as 150 entries would be too much)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a rsync entry? Is it a bash command line invoking rsync?

Comment: Yes gentlemen, I want to make exactly what it describes @PierreFrançois

Comment: about rsync entry. I edditet post/question because message is too long for a comment :)

Comment: The way you run the processes makes me feel that there is only one *rsync* operation at a time for each value of `$i`. If the maximum value of $i is 100, you are still below the maximum you want to allow of 200 processes. So you don't have to program a system for waiting, but a system to multiply the amount of processes. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the maximum value of $i is 100, with your code above you are still below the maximum you want to allow of 200 processes.

So a solution would be to run twice as much processes. I suggest you to divide your main loop `for i in $(seq 1 $rsyncs); do ...` in two loops running concurrently, introduced by resp. `for i in $(seq 1 2 $rsyncs); do ...` for the odd values of `$i`, and `for i in $(seq 2 2 $rsyncs); do ...` for the even values of `$i`.

```
for i in $(seq 1 2 $rsyncs); do         # i = 1 3 5 ...
    while read r; do 
        rsync $rsyncopts backup@$host:$remotepath/$ri $r 2>&1 | 
            tee $tmpdir/$i.dirlist.log ; 
    done < $tmpdir/$i.dirlist &
done &                                  # added an ampersand here
for i in $(seq 2 2 $rsyncs); do         # i = 2 4 6 ...
    while read r; do 
        rsync $rsyncopts backup@$host:$remotepath/$ri $r 2>&1 | 
            tee $tmpdir/$i.dirlist.log ; 
    done < $tmpdir/$i.dirlist &
done
```

**Edit:** Since my approach above doesn't convince you, let us try something completely different. First, create a list of all the processes you want to run and store these in an array:

```
processes=()                      # create an empty bash array
for i in $(sed 1 $rsyncs); do
  while read r; do 
                                  # add the full rsync command line to the array
    processes+=("rsync $rsyncopts backup@$host:$remotepath/$ri $r 2>&1 | tee $tmpdir/$i.dirlist.log");
  done < $tmpdir/$i.dirlist 
done
```

Once you have that array, launch say 200 processes, and then enter a loop to wait a process to finish and launch the next one:

```
for ((j=0;j<200;j++)); do
  $processes[$j]&                 # launch processes in background
done

while [ ! -z "$processes[$j]" ] ; do
  wait                            # wait one process finishes
  $processes[((j++))]&            # launch one more process
done
```

Please try this and tell us.

Comment: OK, but it does not change so much. It is not a problem run every command one by one from each file $tmpdir/$i.dirlist.

The problem is when in each file is e.g 100 commands - there are also 100 files so simple mathematics 100*100 = 10.000 running command at the same time ! :/
That is my main problem, how to manage it to run only 1 command from each file (files are too 100) now wait until all jobs complete before continuing  (e.g. - for loop - ps auxf |grep .... |wc -l  )  if <100 = run next command :)

Comment: with the use of your solution, it ends with an error: syntax error near unexpected token `(' for line where is : $processes[((j++))]&

Answer (score 0):

with an example of use

```
for ARG in  $*; do
    command $ARG &
    NPROC=$(($NPROC+1))
    if [ "$NPROC" -ge 4 ]; then
        wait
        NPROC=0
    fi
done
```